# stratum-mining how to setup

Tags: bitcoin, mining

here are some lines of a configuration file for stratum protocol:

```
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--host', dest='host', type=str, default='198.20.177.17', help='Hostname of Stratum mining pool')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', dest='port', type=int, default=8338, help='Port of Stratum mining pool')
    parser.add_argument('-sh', '--stratum-host', dest='stratum_host', type=str, default='198.20.177.17', help='On which network interface listen for stratum miners. Use "localhost" for listening on internal IP only.')
    parser.add_argument('-sp', '--stratum-port', dest='stratum_port', type=int, default=8344, help='Port on which port listen for stratum miners.')
    parser.add_argument('-oh', '--getwork-host', dest='getwork_host', type=str, default='198.20.177.17', help='On which network interface listen for getwork miners. Use "localhost" for listening on internal IP only.')
    parser.add_argument('-gp', '--getwork-port', dest='getwork_port', type=int, default=3334, help='Port on which port listen for getwork miners. Use another port if you have bitcoind RPC running on this machine already.')
```

Can anyone explain me what values should i put in each parameter? I am really confused...

Comment: Read the `help` for each one. Why are you editing the file? Just run `script.py --help`.

Comment: i have already read --help... but i cant understand in which parameter i will put the existing working port and where the "Stratum" port...